# I can't either insert or fetch data to sqlite3 database, python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
# Create a database or connect to one
conn = sqlite3.connect("tasks_database.db")

# Create the cursor of the database
c = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
            task_name text
        )""")    


def query_func():
        # Create database or connect to one
        connect = sqlite3.connect("tasks_database.db")
        # Create Cursor
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        # Query the database
        cursor.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM tasks ")
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        print(records)
    
def final_crtb_func():
    print("Submit Button Called")
    crtb_func()
    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = sqlite3.connect("tasks_database.db")
    # Create Cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    # Insert to Table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (:task_name)",
    {
        "task_name": inbox_entry.get()
    }
    )
    # Commit Changes
    conn.commit()
    # Close Connection
    conn.close()
    # Create Cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I called these functions but when I say print `records` it prints a blank list, although It should have the value of an entry. Any Help?
Note: I made sure that I clicked the button that had the command of the final_crtb_fuc

Comment: Did you execute `final_crtb_func()` before `query_func()`?

Comment: Note that the last line `c = conn.cursor()` inside `final_crtb_func()` will raise exception because `conn` is a closed database.

Comment: Also if there are other fields in `tasks` table that cannot be NULL, then the INSERT SQL will fail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, so I don't understand what you mean
What should I edit
Regarding the First comment, Yes I clicked the button added to called the `final_crtb_func` first
and I edited the code to the define in the beginning can you review it?

Comment: You should update your code to include missing parts so that it is a [mre].